# Visualforce object

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I'm creating a visualforce page and I'm coming across an issue. Here is the scenario:

We have a few picklist fields in our opportunities that we use to track the products(items that we sell) we sell. Each product has important details that we use to understand the product in the market, such as what the product is used for, or when the product was introduced into the marked... and so on.

I'm creating a product page using visualforce that allows the sales person to select a product from the picklist and ideally the product information would show up below it. I am able to get that done, but what I have not been able to do is to pull a list of all the opportunities that have that product selected in their picklist. Is it possible? I have read a few articles and tutorials and I haven't been able to find a solution.

**Update: Sept 26th**

My apologies about the confusion.
We have a section in the Opportunity Object that has information about the items that we manufacture and sell. These items are in a picklist field, which the sales person selects when creating the opportunity. Each of these items have medical information that we would like to provide to the sales team without having them wasting time searching online for information. So... what we are trying to do is create a custom object that would have that same picklist field in the top of the page and all the information below once the sales person selects the item in the picklist. I also would like to have a section in that custom object where all the opportunities related to that selected item would be displayed (just like opportunities are displayed in the account object).

I was told after doing a lot of research that it is only possible through visualforce. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include some illustrative markup that you already have.

Comment: Hello Adrian. I rather not include an image of the company sfdc. I don't want to violate any company policy. I'll try to explain again.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do this via a query:

```
Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Name, CloseDate, AccountId, StageName
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Id IN 
       (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id = :productId)];
```

At this point, you could put opps into a list or whatever you'd like and display it on the page.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean product as in OpportunityLineItem.

Comment: @Kamara Well, however you've organized your data, it's really just a matter of writing the appropriate query.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but it sounds like you have products stored as a picklist value within the oppty's. I also am assuming that you are looking to create a list view for yourself and the end users to view the oppty's that have these products.

If you want to create a quick list view just open the oppty tab and click "create new view" fill out the required fields and select the field you need to filter (product picklist) and select the value you want.

If the products are a totally separate object and there is a picklist in the oppty that is somehow controlling the related object we might need some further clarification from you.